# Can I set the File Time option for a TFS workspace with the tf.exe workspace command?

Tags: tfs

I would like to set the option File Time = Checkin on workspaces that are created with the tf.exe workspace command. In the Visual Studio 2013 Workspaces editor there is a field for this setting in the Advanced section and it defaults to Current Time.

The build server is creating workspaces with tf.exe and getting the code which then timestamps all the files to current time but I would like them to be time stamped with the last checkin time.

Is it possible to set this option on the command line so I that can include it in my build process?

BTW: If I get the timestamps to match last checkin I can speed up the copy process when deploying my websites by only copying the newer files. Currently it just copies everything even it is has not changed because the timestamps change on every build.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can configure the file time setting with the `filetime` option.  For example:

```
tf workspace MYWORKSPACE /filetime:checkin
```

Comment: I would link to the MSDN docs for `tf workspace` but it appears that the version selector is busted and only the 2010 docs (which lack `/filetime`) are available at the moment.

Comment: That works perfectly! The usage message on tf.exe workspace clearly shows that option. I must have missed it because of the docs issue you point out.